# Web.config Transform

Tags: web-config, transform, web-deployment-project

I have a config that has multiple connection strings.  They all point to the same database server.  Is there a way to replace a portion of the web.config, i.e.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Conn1" connectionString="...DataSource=server1;Initial Catalog=DBName..." />
<add name="Conn2" connectionString="...DataSource=server1;Initial Catalog=DBName2..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

I want to change server1 with server 2.  I could do this...

```
<add xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="Conn1" connectionString="...DataSource=server2;Initial Catalog=DBName..." />
<add xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="Conn2" connectionString="...DataSource=server2;Initial Catalog=DBName..." />
```

but wanted to see if there was a more all-inclusive way.

Answer (score 0):

According the [msdn documentation of web.config transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) there is no possibility for this kind of transformation. You can only do Replace, Insert, InsertBefore, InsertAfter, Remove, RemoveAll, RemoveAttributes and SetAttributes transformations.